# Extracting HDF subdataset to raster or data.frame in R

Tags: r, hdfs, raster, gdal

Currently I'm trying to work with CALIPSO LiDAR data. The files are distributed in HDF4 (checked it with HDFView). The subdataset I'm interested is the Cloud Top Height, which is stored in a simple table (56160 rows, 5 columns):

[image: table]

So far, I tried two things:

**A) Converting HDF subdataset to GeoTiff using gdal_translate (gdalUtils package)**

```
# Get a list of sds names
sds <- get_subdatasets('C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\NASA Sat Data\\Cloud Layer Data\\CAL_LID_L2_333mCLay-ValStage1-V3-01.2011-08-16T03-02-01ZN.hdf')

# Isolate name of subdataset and convert
name <- sds[25]
filename <- 'Cloud_Top_Height_Test.tif'
gdal_translate(name, dst_dataset = filename)

# Load the Geotiff created into R
r <- raster(filename)

# fix extent, projection and negative values
e <- extent(-80.016243, 64.831413, -179.183868, -1.711731)
r <- setExtent(r, e)
values(r)[values(r) < 0] = 0 # replace -9999 with NA
crs(r) <- '+proj=utm +zone=28 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'
```

The result was a raster file which was obviously missing any spatial information (dimensions, extend, crs, resolution), that's why I fixed some things afterwards.

This is the result: [image].

As you can see, the result are some strange lines where it should be square pixels. I suppose I'm missing some statements in the `gdal_translate` call maybe? Also, all the adjustments afterwards seem a bit stuporous or let's say 'unprofessional'.

**B) Converting the table (subdataset) into a data frame (to convert it into a raster in an second step)**

A few days ago I came up with the idea to convert the subdataset (which is essentially 'only' a table) to a data frame and convert it in a second step into a raster, where I specify all spatial information 'from scratch' rather than adjusting it afterwards as in my first attempt. Still, I found no commands/packages to do so and I'm still not confident that this is the right way.

**What I need in the end:** A proper (georeferenced etc) raster (56160 rows, 5 columns) holding the values of the subdataset from the HDF4 file.

**My question:** How can I extract a HDF4 subdataset and convert it to a raster having the specifications mentioned above?

Any help is greatly appreciated (and since this is my first post at SO: sorry, if this question is missing any forms required in this forum, criticism is also appreciated)

Comment: what's the raw data's coordinate system or projection?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any information on this in the product documentation. It seems the position of the spacecraft is provided in the ECR format. Also, there are two subdatasets ("Longitude" and "Latitude") for each of the 56160 rows, which I assume specifies the spacecraft position.I hope this helps in any way.

Comment: Probably lat lon coordinates, which would mean the dataset is already in  a geographic coordinate system. Try specifying the projection in your `gdal_translate` call.

Comment: I managed to specify the projection in my `gdal_translate` call with the `a_srs` variable, which works fine now. But still, the pixels are distorted as in the image above. I suppose my main issue is the wrong resolution, which is `35.49443, 0.002579196  (x, y)` after the adjustment of the projection, but should be `333m x 333m`.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to specify your resolution in decimal degrees

Answer (score 0):

to convert to dataframe:

```
as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE)
```